# Unable to filter NULLs in DB2 table

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm running a simple 'WHERE [COLUMN] IS NULL' statement but the expected row that I wanted was not retrieved.  I also did a distinct values statement and there were 7 different NULLs.

Is there an explanation for this and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, the current result and the desired result, and the query. (Simplified if complex or big.)

Comment: maybe you have a string datatype column that has the actual value `'NULL'`

Comment: [SELECT DISTINCT CEPMTDATE
FROM KWDB122.KWCEMPL AS A
where a.ccust = '16907'] returns NULL

Comment: [SELECT DISTINCT CEPMTDATE
FROM KWDB122.KWCEMPL AS A
where a.ccust = '16907'
and cepmtdate is null] returns nothing

Comment: @Lamak I tried that but it was for a date field so a string is invalid.

Comment: Can you try with : cepmtdate = '0001-01-01'

Comment: @Dam Your answer was very close!  I formatted the 'null' value as a varchar [varchar_format(cast(cepmtdate as timestamp),'yyyymmdd')] and it came out as 99990101. I would imagine it does the same thing for '0001-01-01' as we've had trouble with that timestamp in the past.  Any idea if this problem is documented?

Answer (score 1):

Basically all comparison operators with NULL return "false" or NULL which are filtered out in a WHERE clause.

So, your query should be:

```
WHERE COLUMN <> 'VALUE' OR COLUMN IS NULL
```

alternatively use COALESCE()

```
WHERE COALESCE(column, '') <> 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks for trying.  I posted the solution in the comments.